# Can we add routing to Delete By Query API in elastic 5.x using java

Tags: java, routes, elasticsearch-5

I'm new to elastic search . I'm trying to add routing to delete documents using Delete By Query API . Wanted to know if there is any way of doing it.[enter link description here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/java-docs-delete-by-query.html#java-docs-delete-by-query)